# $resource as global Service

Tags: angularjs, service, promise, ngresource

the title is not as descriptive as it needs to be but I didnt find a better one.

So in my AngularJS app I have a Settings service.
In this service im maintaining a object queried by $resource.
I am using this approach because I dont want to query my settings all the time again and because other parts of the app needs to be directly influenced by changes to the setting.

The Service:

```
module.factory("Settings", [$resource, function($resource){
  var resource = $resource("path/to/api/settings");
  var settings = resource.get();

  return {
    getSettings: function(){
      return settings;
    }
  };
}]);
```

Usage:

```
module.controller("MyController", ["Settings", function(Settings){
  var self = this;
  self.settings = Settings.getSettings();
  self.result = 0;

  self.aMethod = function(arg){
    //Do some calculate based on settings
    self.settings.then(function(){
      self.result = arg * self.settings.multiplyBy;
    });
  };

  self.setMultiplyBy = function(arg){
     //This will affect all usages where multiplyBy is used
     self.settings.multiplyBy = arg;
     self.settings.$save();
  };

})];
```

The Problem is that I have to check if settings are resolved every time I want to use them.
So I have `.then()` callbacks all over my controllers what looks really dirty and I cant return values out of the callbacks.
So is there an easier way to solve this?
Can I somehow ensure that the settings are loaded before the app runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely wait until certain resources are loaded before showing particular things. The easiest way to do this is probably with `ui-router`, and the `resolve` state property.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    controller: 'MyContoller',
    resolve: {
        settings: function(Settings){
            // return a promise here
            return Settings.getSettings();
        }
    }
});
```

Then inside your controller, you can inject `settings` which will be the resolved (promise fulfilled version) of your settings object.

Read more about ui-router & resolve here:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: Deleted unnecesarry comment. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You may have to fiddle with your service, but if a promise of any kind is returned using the resolve function, it will wait until the promise has been resolved before loading the view. So you need to setup a promise that will only resolve once the data you need is ready for use.